# How do I call out an IEnumerator from another script to a script which also contains IEnumerator?

Tags: unity, c#

It is a Game Manager:

```
public class gm : MonoBehaviour
public IEnumerator spawnTile() .....
```

I want this `IEnumerator spawnTile` to be called on this script:

```
public class gmSidePlatform : MonoBehaviour
 void Start()
{
    NextSpawnSidePlatform.x = 30.5f;
    StartCoroutine(SpawnSidePlatform());
}

IEnumerator SpawnSidePlatform()....
```

I did follow the instructions of calling other scripts by using `Public gm gameManager1;` 
But the variables from the gm script didn't appear on this (`gmSidePlatform`) script. I don't know what to do...

Comment: "the variables from the gm script didnt appear" - that sounds like the same problem as [your previous question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/185022/39518). Please take the time to edit that question to clarify it, according to the feedback in the comments. Aim to share a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example: every line of code we would need to reproduce the problem in a new, empty project. That's the best way to be sure your question is clear, complete, and understandable to someone who has never seen your project.